# Method of Least square

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, least-squares

Sometimes, the method of least squares can be used for problems that, in principle, could not be addressed by the method.

For example, let's suppose we want to find $a$ and $b$ in order to fit the function $\frac{1}{{a + bx}}$ to the points $(x_i, y_i)$ by minimizing
$$min\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m (\frac{1}{a + bx_i} - y_i)^2$$

This minimization is not in a form that the method of least squares can solve.
However, an idea is to find a transformation $T$ such that
$$min\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m [T(\frac{1}{a + bx_i}) - T(y_i)]^2$$
is a problem of least squares. In the given case, if we use $T(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, we will have the minimization of
$$min\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m (a + bx_i - \frac{1}{y_i})^2$$

where we can apply the method of least squares.

Find appropriate transformations for the following functions:

a) $f(x) = ae^{bx}$

b) $f(x) = \frac{1}{{a + bx + cx^2}}$

So, for letter A, I used the transformation $T(x) = \ln(x)$, which provides the desired result. However, in letter B, I'm uncertain about the next steps. How can we transform a quadratic function into a linear function so that we can apply the least squares method?

Comment: Hint: (b) isn't quadratic in the unknowns $a$, $b$, and $c$

Comment: Why would $T(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ not work again?

Comment: @whpowell96 because we don't have the restriction of $c \neq 0$?

Comment: After applying $x\mapsto 1/x$, the function is quadratic in $x$, not the coefficients